# Can't get table (or anything in body) created in JS to display in browser

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have been troubleshooting this for a couple hours and cannot find any syntax errors that I know of. I cannot get the table to display AT. ALL. I truncated the beginning of the code declaring the HTML type and the comment included with the homework. I only have a few weeks experience with JS, have found similar problems on the site but cannot find one that applies to me. Please help me figure out why I cannot get anything other than the logo and address to display! I am not very fluent with HTML. (Due tomorrow)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="list.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var total = 0;
      function amountTotal(){
         var total = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i <= amount.length; i++){
            total = total + amount[i];
         }
         return total;
      }
   </script>

   <title>The Lighthouse</title>
   <link href="lhouse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

   <div id="title">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="The Lighthouse" />
      The Lighthouse<br />
      543 Oak Street<br />
      Owensboro, KY &nbsp;&nbsp;42302<br/>
      (270) 555-7511
   </div>

   <div id="data_list">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.write("<table border='1' rules='rows' cellspacing='0'>");
         document.write("<tr>");
         document.write("<th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Address</th>");
         document.write("</tr>");
            for (var i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
               If (i % == 0) {
                  document.write("<tr>");
               } else {
                  document.write("<tr class='yellowrow'>");
               }
               document.write("<td>"+ date[i] +"</td>");
               document.write("<td class='amt'>"+ amount[i] +"</td>");
               document.write("<td>"+ firstName[i] +"</td>");
               document.write("<td>"+ lastName[i] +"</td>");
               document.write("<td>"+ street[i] +"</ br>");
               document.write(city[i] + ", " + state[i] + " " + zip[i]);
               document.write("</td>");
               document.write("</tr>");
               document.write("</table>");
            }
      </script>

   </div>

   <div id="totals">

      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.write("<table border='1' cellspacing='1'>");
         document.write("<tr>");
         document.write("<th id='sumTitle' colspan='2'>Summary</th>");
         document.write("</tr>");
         document.write("<tr>");
         document.write("<th>Contributors</th>");
         document.write("<td>"+ amount.length +"</th>");
         document.write("</tr>");
         document.write("<tr>");
         document.write("<th>Amount</th>");
         document.write("<td>"+ amountTotal() +"</td>");
         document.write("</tr>");
         document.write("</table>");
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for further information, the amount[] array is included in the list.js file. It is declared using the syntax amount = new Array();

Comment: if you're taking a class where they teach you to use `document.write()`, ask for your money back.

Comment: This is actually week 2. I'm trying to complete this assignment within the bounds of what we have learned in 13 days. The problems seem to start with the div tag having the ID of "data_list." Everything above that displays in the browser.

Comment: I don't care what week it is. They shouldn't ever mention `document.write()`, it's not the appropriate way for Javascript applications to modify the document.

Comment: However it is likely appropriate to introduce non-coding students to it in an effort to teach them how very basic concepts like objects work in the first place. Thanks for the help with my code!

Comment: If your Javascript doesn't seem to be doing anything, the first place you should check is the Javascript console in your browser (use F12 to get into Developer Tools or Firebug). There you would have seen a message about the syntax error that Neeo MENG's answer points out.

Comment: So it seems I'm missing a semicolon before the statement on line 56 'If (i % 2 == 0) document.write("<tr>")' Is there something I'm not catching about nesting an If statement inside a For loop?

Comment: There is no `If (i % 2 == 0)` line -- you're missing the `2`, that's the problem. Also, it's `if`, not `If` -- JS is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed this code?

```
If (i % == 0) {
   document.write("<tr>");
}
```

in the second script block. I think it should be

```
if(i%something == 0)
{
    document.write("<tr>");
}
```

Comment: Probably should be `i % 2 == 0`, it looks like he's just trying to alternate row colors.

Comment: That is correct, it was an attempt to alternate row colors. I have corrected this and cannot see the table yet. Thanks for the good eyes, though!

Comment: It also looks like I neglected to close the script tag in the second script block, which is now also corrected. SO, I can now see the second table on my page, but not the first.